# Does Quartus II suppress report message with the same text?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, quartus

I'm porting a Xilinx ISE project to Quartus II. When I compile that project Quartus crashes with an error: `*** Fatal Error: Access Violation at 0X000007FE88160DE1`. So I'm trying to narrow down the error to a minimal example, which will guide me to a hidden VHDL bug or to a small example, which I can send to Altera.

The project uses a VHDL data structure (record of vectors of records of vectors of ... of basic types) to describe a SoC setup. The simplified structure look like this:

```
SoFPGA System
o-DeviceInstances
| o-Device
|   o-Registers
|   | o-Bitfields
|   o-RegisterMappings
o-Busses
```

I would like to report the full structure to the synthesis log, but Quartus II seems to hide messages if the message text was already printed to the log.

**Example:**

```
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1228): "DeviceInstance 1:" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1229): "  DeviceInstance: Mult32" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1230): "    Device: Mult32" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        0: OperandA0 Reg#=0 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1241): "          0: FieldID=0 (OperandA)" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        1: OperandA1 Reg#=1 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        2: OperandA2 Reg#=2 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        3: OperandA3 Reg#=3 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        4: OperandB0 Reg#=4 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1241): "          0: FieldID=1 (OperandB)" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        5: OperandB1 Reg#=5 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        6: OperandB2 Reg#=6 WR" (NOTE)
Info (10635): ... at pb.pkg.vhdl(1234): "        7: OperandB3 Reg#=7 WR" (NOTE)
```

The 'FieldID' message is only printed once per 'Operand[A|B]'. There is no FieldID line after operands A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2, B3.

So I tried to add an unique number (`salt`) to each report line. For that I defined a shared variable and defined a function `salty` that increments salt in every report statement.

**Variable and function:**

```
shared variable salt : NATURAL := 0;

impure function salty return STRING is
begin
  salt := salt + 1;
  return INTEGER'image(salt);
end function;
```

**Usage:**

```
report salty & "pb_CreateRegisterRO:" severity NOTE;
```

But unfortunately, salty always returns "0". Quartus II supports VHDL'08 features. Should I implement the shared variable as a protected type and compile it in VHDL'08 mode?

**How can I print all report statement lines to the synthesis report?**

---

**Off topic question:**
Is someone interested in helping me finding the reason why Quartus crashes? I stripped the project to 6 VHDL files. I think this problem is to specific for a SO question. [Contact](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/AUTHORS#L5)